[OpenApiSecurity("bearer_auth" is not working in .NET 8 isolated out-of-process model
I am working on Azure .NET 8 functions and the following function decorator is not working.
[OpenApiSecurity("bearer_auth", SecuritySchemeType.Http, Scheme = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Bearer, BearerFormat = "JWT")]

I have tried the following.
[Function("Function1")]

[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "oauth.flows.implicit", tags: new[] { "oauth" }, Summary = "OAuth implicit flows", Description = "This shows the OAuth implicit flows", Visibility = `OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]

[OpenApiSecurity("bearer_auth", SecuritySchemeType.Http, Scheme = OpenApiSecuritySchemeType.Bearer, BearerFormat = "JWT")]
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(IEnumerable<string>), Summary = "successful operation", Description = "successful operation")]

public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{
     _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
      return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
}

I am getting the following error when I test in Swagger UI:


Bearer authentication requires OpenAPI v. 3. Make sure you have set your OpenApiVersion to OpenApiVersionType.V3 as explained here:
public class MyOpenApiConfigurationOptions : IOpenApiConfigurationOptions
{
    ...

    public OpenApiVersionType OpenApiVersion { get; set; } = OpenApiVersionType.V3;

    ...
}

